# Issue accessing DB , DB cursor object and calling the execute method - Flask web application and Apache

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

This is a simple Flask web application hosted in Apache on the Amazon lightsail cloud server.

I am able to a load my web page in the browser, enter my data into my form and select the submit button.

Issues:
(a) After selecting the submit button I and getting an internal server error and data fails to insert into my sqlite db
(Internal Server Error
Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.)

(b) Error logs indicate that database object (conn) is of 'NoneType'.

File "/var/www/wordrubble/app.py", line 84, in form_entry
conn.execute(sql_query, data)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'execute'

Note:

When running the scripts on my local (MAC) environment the form data saves to my db file without an issue. I am thinking it is a configuration issue with Apache/Wsgi.

Versions:

ubuntu 18.04

Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)

mod_wsgi/4.5.17 Python/3.6 configured

Flask 2.0.2

Sqlite3

```
.
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── app.py
├── game_env.db
├── logs
│   ├── access.log
│   └── error.log
├── requirements.txt
├── static
│   ├── Front_Image_Package.png
│   └── wr.css
├── templates
│   └── wr.html
└── wordrubble.wsgi
```

app.py file

```
DATABASE = 'game_env.db'


def create_connection():
    # create a database connection to the SQLite database
    conn = None
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)

    return conn

@app.route('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def form_entry():
    entered_name = None
    entered_email = None
    form = NameForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        sql_query = 'INSERT INTO users(name,email,date_and_time) VALUES(?,?,?)'
        todays_date = datetime.datetime.now()
        entered_name = form.entered_name.data
        entered_email = form.entered_email.data
        conn = create_connection()
        data = [entered_name, entered_email, todays_date]
        conn.execute(sql_query, data)
        conn.commit()

        form.entered_name.data = ' '
        form.entered_email.data = ' '
    return render_template("wr.html", entered_name=entered_name, entered_email=entered_email, form=form)
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved:
Resolution -
I specified the exact location of the database file and it was able to be recognized.
DATABASE = '/var/www/wordrubble/game_env.db'

Now the db is showing that it is locked, looks like it is tied up while other threads are trying to access it.Another issue for another time...

Comment: So you had to be more precise when setting the `DATABASE` variable. Could you edit your answer so that this is made more explicit? Try to explain the reasons behind the necessity for complete path in the `DATABASE` variable